# How to pass any HtmlControl to a function as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just wrote a function that checks if an HTML control is hidden or not.
how can i change the type System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow of the parameter myControl to a type that will support any HTML control type. i prefer to not write specific function for any html control.

```
 public static bool IsUIElementHidden(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow myControl)
        {            
            if ((myControl.Style["display"] ?? "").ToLower().Equals("none") || (myControl.Style["visibility"] ?? "").ToLower().Equals("none"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I tried to use the type WebControl but when i am passing the control to the function i am getting an error.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: NB `visibility`'s not-visible value is `hidden` (or possibly `collapse`), not `none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your choices based on the object hierarchy:

```
System.Object 
  System.Web.UI.Control
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl
      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
```

Considering that `Style` is inherited from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl` I would choose that:

```
static bool IsUIElementHidden(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl myControl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `Style` property, which belongs to `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl`.

So this should work:

```
public static bool IsUIElementHidden(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl myControl)
        {            
            if ((myControl.Style["display"] ?? "").ToLower().Equals("none") || (myControl.Style["visibility"] ?? "").ToLower().Equals("none"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a few control types you expect to pass to your function, you could pass a generic control and a string to determine what kind of control to cast to. Then, in your function, cast the generic control to a specific type.

```
 Private Sub setControl(ByVal control As Control, ByVal myType As String)
       Select Case myType 
            Case myType  = "label"
                Dim newLabel As New Label
                newLabel = CType(control, Label)

            Case myType  = "textbox"
                Dim newTextBox As New TextBox
                newTextBox = CType(control, TextBox)
        End Select
 end sub
```

You might even be able to forgo the string and use reflection to determine what type of control it is.